# Jsonp proxy Exampple, send request to our own site instead of sencha site

Tags: json, extjs4.1

I'm designing a jsonp example where I want to make a call to some different domain, so I'm making a call to http://www.walkingtree.in/forums/topics-browse-remote.php, instead of http://www.sencha.com/forum/topics-browse-remote.php.

The data is printing same format in both the case, but while executing am getting some error in console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : topics-browse-remote.php:1,
>   but there is no such error.

When I am watching the response there is only one change in response i.e when I'm making call to sencha forum then the response is coming inside `Ext.data.JsonP.callback1({......})`

and in the other forum case its coming simply like this `{.............}`

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. The problem was there in the php file. Inthis type of request generally one queryString will go with callback, so we need to get the callback and append it to our response so that response will come properly.

```
Sample php code :
<? php
$callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];
$output = array('a'=>'any text', 'b'=>'some other Text');
if ($callback) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($output) . ');';
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
?>

Thanks
Tapaswini
```